# Simple .hide Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get my button to hide a ul element but nothing seems to be working. The test alert works just fine but the hide event does not. I have checked that the CSS selector is correct.

Here is my current script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").on("click", function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".b3_archive_testimonial_category_list").hide();
      alert("HI");
    });
  });
});
```

Had to format it weirdly to get it to fit the code element on StackOverflow...

[Image of the element to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib4eo.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: you're trying to preventDefault but you aren't passing event to the function. You could probably figure this out by looking at your developer console.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Pass event to the function `$(".trigger").on("click", function(event){`

Comment: too many class in your code, with no css values for...

Comment: @imjared Just looked at the console, nothing is logged when clicking the button.

Comment: @Rikin Just added this but still no luck.

Comment: @MrJ Could you elaborate? Setting the class to visibility: hidden works via the style sheet but does not work with the button.

Comment: @Donovan Rucastle class are for css rules over elements, and this is 'cascading' so no need to put class names everywhere. if you really need to access 0ne element use id

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `.trigger` is an `<a>` tag, which is the reason why [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is used. In this context, using this event method will keep the page from jumping when a link is clicked.

- If that is in fact the reason, pass the [**event Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event):

  `$(".trigger").on("click", function(`**event**`) {...`
- If `.trigger` isn't an `<a>` tag, remove `event.preventDefault()`.

Also, unwrap this:

```
jQuery(function($) {...});
```

it's unnecessary.

---

### Demo

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".b3_archive_testimonial_category_list").hide();
});
```

```html
<a href='#' class='trigger'>Trigger</a>
<ul class='b3_archive_testimonial_category_list'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the event parameter in the function:

```
$(".trigger").on("click", function(event) {...}
```

Now your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `toggle()` to hide and show the items on a element click event.

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".b3_archive_testimonial_category_list").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='trigger'>Trigger</a>
<ul class='b3_archive_testimonial_category_list'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer based on a few of your responses.

The main issue seemed to be with too many CSS classes or just the fact that I was targeting a ul CSS class. I have enclosed it in a div and made the div show and hide. This seems to work the best.

Secondly, the responses stating I have not passed the event function were correct:

```
$(".trigger").on("click", function(event) {...}
```

My current code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.dropdown').hide();
jQuery('.trigger').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery(".dropdown").slideToggle();
jQuery('.trigger').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question here is the answer. You must include jquery library file to run your code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").on("click", function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".b3_archive_testimonial_category_list").hide();
      alert("HI");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<button type="button" class="trigger">Click</button>

<ul class='b3_archive_testimonial_category_list'>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```